# Highcharts not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I am using a simple html page with Highcharts version 3.0 and jQuery 9.1. It is working in all browsers except IE8. Here is a code which I copied from highcharts demo line chart.

Head tag files

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });
 </script>
```

`
The error IE8 is giving is
[image]

Please guide me what I am doing wrong. Many thanks

Comment: Which version of IE8 do you have?

Comment: version 8.0.7601.17514

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my machine and it started working. Windows was pending some updates install, not sure how that one helped :)